# Form Recognizer/Computer Vision pbm file support

Tags: computer-vision, azure-form-recognizer

I was given a few files with a pbm extension (and I am told it is Portable Bitmap Image file).

I notice on the Form Recognizer API site that it does not support this type of file. Does anyone know if it will ever be supported, and if not, is there any way to convert this into a tif "easily"?

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Comment: ImageMagick can convert that. So you could use Python Wand, which is based upon imagemagick. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.1/ and https://imagemagick.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not plan to support pbm files. You may try to use ImageMagick (https://imagemagick.org) to convert the images to a supported format.